# Exclude/ignore certain column on update trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I want to exclude certain column from firing a trigger on updates, I tried few variations of the code shown here, but it doesn't work (not updating `import_timestamp`) when `processed_on` was not null before update.

I tried adding this commented out OR clause but still the same. Any ideas?

Expected behaviour is to update `import_timestamp` on update on any column except `processed_on`, and do not update it on `processed_on` updates (it's not possible that `processed_on` update will occur in same transaction with other columns).

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e051eee3ebdd4af4c0e0565408b55291)

```
create table test
(
    id serial,
    some_value integer,
    import_timestamp timestamp,
    processed_on timestamp
);

insert into test(some_value, import_timestamp, processed_on) 
values (1312, '2021-02-02 20:00:00', '2021-02-02 20:44:00'),
       (124, '2021-02-02 20:10:00', null),
       (500, '2021-02-02 20:20:00', null);
 
 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_update_import_timestamp (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.processed_on = NEW.processed_on 
    --OR (OLD.processed_on = null AND NEW.processed_on = null)
    THEN    NEW.import_timestamp = now();
    ELSE 
        NEW.import_timestamp = OLD.import_timestamp;
    
END IF;
    RETURN NEW; 
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER test_update_trg 
  BEFORE UPDATE 
  ON test
  
FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_update_import_timestamp();
  
  update test set some_value  = 444 where id in (1,3);
select * from test order by 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a new `import_timestamp` for rows 1 and 3.  I believe this does what you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_update_import_timestamp (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.processed_on is not distinct from NEW.processed_on 
    THEN NEW.import_timestamp = now();
    ELSE NEW.import_timestamp = OLD.import_timestamp;
    
END IF;
    RETURN NEW; 
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=66186fc802bb2a2944703aa59c072898) is a db<>fiddle.